# Tem como eu ver a implementação dos códigos da API do Java?

Tags: java

Estou iniciando em Java, e acho super legal a vasta biblioteca do Java, com muitas classes e métodos que facilitam o nosso trabalho. Até no livro do Deitel recomenda o uso por vários motivos.

Eu uso alguns métodos, mas como estou iniciando, gostaria de entender a implementação de alguns. Tem alguma maneira de eu acessá-los?

Comment: qual IDE está usando?

Comment: Estou usando NetBeans 8.1

Comment: de uma olhada nesse site [JavaCompile](http://www.javadecompilers.com/). aqui é possível descompilar os arquivos.

Comment: Se tiver falando do código nativo do JDK, este site é possivel ver o source de quase tudo http://developer.classpath.org/doc/overview-summary.html

Comment: Sim Diego, é isso que estou falando. Obrigado! Por exemplo, como eu acho a implementação do "Arrays.copyOf()" nesse site?

Comment: Renan : http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/Arrays.html Good luck! :)

Comment: Sua pergunta fala sobre "Implementação" o que quer dizer o código dos métodos, mas me parece que você quer a documentação. Se realmente quiser ver o código uma boa fonte é o [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/), veja [aqui a do Arrays.copyOf](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.copyOf%28boolean%5B%5D%2Cint%29) por exemplo. Caso queira a documentação veja os comentários que o pessoal fez acima.

Comment: A documentação eu tenho a que a Oracle disponibiliza no próprio site, que explica como funciona os métodos. Mas o que queria ver mesmo era a implementação deles. O site que o Diego passou e o seu ajudam. Obrigado! =)

Comment: Obrigado a todos que se dispuseram a ajudar =)

Comment: A JDK vem com o código fonte das partes escritas em Java (no arquivo src.zip). No NetBeans basta segurar Ctrl e clicar na classe ou método que ele pula para a implementação.

Answer (score 0):

Como mencionado nos comentários a fonte do JDK (as bibliotecas do java) estão dispomíveis no src.zip, incluido com o SDK. Nota que o meu SDK está numa directoria diferente. Normalmente encontra-se em `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\...` ou `C:\Program Files\Java\...`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Além disso as fontes também estão [disponíveis no github](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/tree/master/src/share/classes/java)